# Where should I install node.js?

Tags: node.js, centos, cpanel, whm

I'm wondering in which directory I should go to install node.js on a CentOS 5/cPanel server by executing the following commands mentioned in the Wiki:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout origin/v0.4 # optional.  Note that master is unstable.
export JOBS=2 # optional, sets number of parallel commands.
mkdir ~/local
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node
make
make install
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/node/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

Please advise.

Comment: Install node.js where ever you want. It should add itself to the path nicely. just get the source code, configure, make, make install. Btw I recommend 0.4.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more conventional locations for a multi-user system are:

```
/usr/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

But as @Raynos stated you can put it wherever you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I like to install latest version of node.js using something called [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Like Raynos said you are better of using node v0.4.8 instead of development branch to avoid broken packages.

Comment: I personally found that `nvm` can cause problems with other command line node.js tools. You need to know what your doing with nvm.

Comment: I have not yet experienced any problems with that and I am using `nodemon` without any problems for example, but you might be right I guess...

Comment: It depends on whether you said it up properly. I made a mess of my node.js installation using nvm. It's a good tool, you can just shoot yourself in the foot if your `npm isntalling` libraries left & right.